# Will a North American SNES Power Adapter Fit In a Super Famicom?

Tags: region-lock, snes

Today, on eBay, I bought myself a Super Famicom for $23.80 shipped, coming from Japan. It's pretty dirty and the case has turned yellow from oxidation, but I thought it was pretty cool and intend on restoring it. Though I have every home Nintendo console for the North American market, this is the first console I have ever purchased that was originally sold for use in another country.

I have a question regarding this:

**Will a North American SNES power adapter jack physically fit in a Super Famicom?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use an unofficial cable to power a console?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262197/is-it-safe-to-use-an-unofficial-cable-to-power-a-console)

Comment: @Timelord64 I see the similarities between my post and that one, but mine is more about regional differences, not being too cheap to buy the real deal.

Comment: they seem like two differant things, but in actual fact, the differences are trivial, at best. they still have the same implications, you still have to look out for the same things, and they still result from using "unofficial cable" (Your cable might be made by the same company, **but it is not the original cable**, and thats where your probem derives from.

Comment: You will also find the answer also answers this question (you just have to match V, A and polarity; if your wall outputs a differant voltage, get a transformer to step up or step down)

Comment: @Timelord64 Okay, I'll edit it because I still don't know if the plug will fit in the first place.

Comment: japan to us, no, but you can get adapters. but then, they are visually distinct, you could tell that by looking at it.

Comment: just make sure you do read through the other answer. a lot of users will say "it fits. no worries, let's do this" and blow up their consoles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no**, an SNES adapter will not physically fit into a Super Famicom.

As a general rule, you really should just use the proper power supply anyway.

If you look around online you'll find plenty of cases of people using a North American Sega Genesis (Type 1) power adapter to run a Super Famicom without issue, but understand that there's always a risk in using an adapter other than the one intended for your console.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one more thing maybe you or @Timelord64 could help me with. Is it safe, as in won't ruin my Super Famicom, to use the original Japanese adapter rated for 100 V AC input with my 120 V AC US mains power? Interestingly, both US GBA SP power adapters I own and every one online I see is rated for 100 V AC, but I've used it without noticing the difference for months, even being plugged in all the time, but the SF is different from the GBA SP, so I don't know.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Technically it works, but it's one of those things where the fact that you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_. The higher voltage can damage a Japanese adapter over time and in turn harm your system. While there's also a fair chance it _won't_ happen, I'm not going to gamble with my import consoles when an inexpensive converter like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Simran-SM-500J-Japanese-Transformer-Converts/dp/B005GHGPK6) eliminates the risk and outputs enough power to run all my Japanese devices simultaneously with a power strip.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have one of those step-down regulators?

Comment: I actually have a couple. I use model I linked above for my Japanese game consoles and other toys/gadgets because it gives plenty of juice to leave a half dozen of them plugged in, but I also have a few small kitchen appliances from Japan which take a crapton more energy than electronic devices, so I had to buy a more expensive converter with higher output for them